# Using DSInternals Powershell module in C# application

Tags: c#, powershell, active-directory

I am creating a WinForms application where I am showing the attributes of all users, such as SamAccountName, DistinguishedName and NTHash (Hashed value of a password). I am doing this by using using DSInternals.Replication, and want to use the Test-PasswordQuality command, which displays the information about all available password in AD, such as accounts with similar password etc.

Is it possible to do so, by not running it as a powershell command? (e.g Get-ADReplAccount -All -Server 'lon-dc1.contoso.com' | Test-PasswordQuality -WeakPasswordHashesSortedFile pwned-passwords-ntlm-ordered-by-hash-v5.txt). Rather by maybe creating a separate class or by using the code written for that specific class, in DSInternals.Powershell github folder? (https://github.com/MichaelGrafnetter/DSInternals/blob/master/Src/DSInternals.PowerShell/Commands/Misc/TestPasswordQualityCommand.cs)

Comment: Sure. What's stopping you?

Comment: I mean I am not really sure how I should call or use the required methods, most of them are private/protected, and the class itself extends PSCmdletEx, mainly orientating for PowerShell cmdlets, or maybe I am not proficient enough in C# development, which is probably why I am still stuck with this issue :)